# probability of outcome in small sample size

Tags: probability, statistics, law-of-large-numbers

I read about the law of small numbers (psychological phenomenon related to the statistical law of large numbers), where the following example is given:

> Suppose a drug is effective in 80% of patients. If five patients are
> treated, how many will respond?
>
> Many people reason that 80% means 4 out of 5, so if 5 people are
> treated, exactly 4 will respond. Always.
>
> Others understand that things are not guaranteed to work out so
> neatly, but they still believe that it is highly likely that 4 people
> would respond. Maybe a 90% chance.
>
> In fact, there’s only a 41% chance that exactly 4 would respond out of
> a sample of 5.

Can someone explain how they got to 41%, by way of example:

If there is a 50% chance of heads and you flip 10 times whats the chance that you get 5 heads?

Comment: Make yourself familiar with [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). The answer on your last question is $2^{-10}\binom{10}5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of patients who respond to the treatment follows a Binomial distribution with $n=5$ and $p=0.8$. The probability of exactly four patients responding is
$$ {5 \choose 4} \times 0.8^4 \times 0.2 = 0.4096 $$